# How to include summernote editor to angular 2 webpack?

Tags: angular, summernote

I will use [summernote editor](https://github.com/summernote/summernote) to angular 2 webpack? Unfortunately summernote don't have npm so i download js file and css file manually, how to include it in angular 2 webpack? thank you

Comment: Here's the [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/summernote)

Comment: @adriancarriger i am sorry i have another problem, i have success install summernote via `npm`, and state in vendor.ts `import 'summernote/dist/'`  but get an error : `Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'summernote/dist'` what is the solution?

Comment: I probably would need a lot more information. I would recommend creating a new question and make sure to include the code you're using. Even a link to your repository could be helpful. After creating the question, just leave me a comment here with a link to the question. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until better way... I have a work around until this is fixed @ github.com/martinsvb/ng2-summernote

My temporary work around is simply using Jquery for now in class component. see demo:
https://github.com/nickgoodrow/SummernoteNg2_WorkAround

demo: **https://ng2summernote.firebaseapp.com/Demo**

Comment: Hey, Nick. I am facing the same problem. I have added both css and js file on index.html file on angular 2. But getting error i.e summernote is not a functions.